# Set a shape hyperlink to a pivot table address?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, pivot-table

I'm trying to make a shape hyperlink to a pivot table. There are multiple tables on the sheet and the locations change. I cannot link to a specific cell.

```
ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws_name.Shapes("Rectangle 1"), Address:=ws_name.PivotTables("Pivot_Name").TableRange1.Address, _
        SubAddress:=ws_name.PivotTables("Pivot_Name").TableRange1.Address
```

This is what I was attempting. Any ideas or guidance, as this does not work. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach - put this in a regular module and link all your "show pivot table" buttons to it:

```vb
Sub ShowPivotTable()
    Dim shpName As String, arr
    shpName = Application.Caller  'The name of the clicked-on shape
                                  '  e.g. "show_PivotTable1"
    arr = Split(shpName, "_", 2)  'split shape name to array
    If UBound(arr) > 0 Then       'make sure there was an underscore in the name
        Debug.Print arr(1)        'arr(1) is the name of the pivot table
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables(arr(1)).DataBodyRange.Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Name your buttons e.g.:

- show_PivotTable1
- showPivotTable2

where the part of the name after `_` is the name of the pivot table you want to select.

As an alternative to naming the shapes, you could pass the name of the pivot table directly to the called macro - see https://www.teachexcel.com/excel-tutorial/1893/pass-arguments-to-a-macro-called-from-a-button-or-sheet-in-excel for how to do that.